# Finite morphism is stable under base change.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, morphism

In the scheme theory, there is a notion 'finite morphism'.

I find the fact that a finite morphism is stable under base change in the Wikipedia. (Link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_morphism)

But I cannot prove or find why.

How can I prove it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is [EGAII, Prop. 6.1.5(iii)], although I'm sure you can find a better reference.

**Proposition.** *If $f\colon X \to S$ is a finite morphism, then the morphism $f' \colon X \times_S S' \to S'$ is finite for all base extensions $g\colon S' \to S$.*

*Proof.* Cover $S$ with open affines $V_i = \operatorname{Spec} B_i$. By the definition of a finite morphism, we have $f^{-1}(V_i) = \operatorname{Spec} A_i$, where each $A_i$ is finitely generated as modules over $B_i$.

The sets $g^{-1}(V_i)$ form an open cover for $S'$, and we can cover these $g^{-1}(V_i)$ with open affines $V'_{ij} = \operatorname{Spec} B'_{ij}$. We claim that the preimages
$$f^{\prime-1}(V'_{ij}) = X \times_S V'_{ij} \cong f^{-1}(V_i) \times_{V_i} V'_{ij}$$
of the $V'_{ij}$ are affine, with coordinate rings $A'_{ij}$ that are finitely generated as modules over $B'_{ij}$. Note that the isomorphism above is by the construction of the fiber product; see [Hartshorne, Thm. 3.3, Step 7].

First, affinity of $f^{\prime-1}(V'_{ij})$ follows since
$$f^{\prime-1}(V'_{ij}) \cong f^{-1}(V_i) \times_{V_i} V'_{ij} \cong \operatorname{Spec}(A_i \otimes_{B_i} B'_{ij})$$

Now defining $A'_{ij} := A_i \otimes_{B_i} B'_{ij}$, we want to show that $A'_{ij}$ is finitely generated as a module over $B'_{ij}$. Since $A_i$ is finitely generated as a module over $B_i$, we have surjections
$$B_i^{\oplus n_i} \twoheadrightarrow A_i$$
for each $i$. Now applying $-\otimes_{B_i} B'_{ij}$, by the right-exactness of the tensor product, we have surjections
$$B_{ij}^{\prime\oplus n_i} \twoheadrightarrow A_i \otimes_{B_i} B'_{ij} =: A'_{ij}$$
for each $i,j$. Thus, $A'_{ij}$ is a $B'_{ij}$-algebra, which is finitely generated as a module over $B'_{ij}$. $\blacksquare$

Comment: How do you know $f^{-1}(V_i)$ is affine? You implicitly assumed that $f^{-1}(V_i)=\text{Spec}(A_i)$ for some $A_i$, right?

Comment: Dear @rmdmc89, Yes, this is part of the definition for $f$ being a finite morphism. Reading this answer now, I realize that I never said where the $A_i$ came from; I apologize for the confusion!

Comment: Out of curiosity: if $g$ is a finite morphism, is there a way to relate the degree of $f$ with the degrees of $f$ and $g$?

Comment: @rmdmc89 According to [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/77598/33088) by Georges Elencwajg, you need some extra flatness assumptions for that to hold.